# 'BaseQuery' object is not callable when using func count and group by in SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to query the SQLAlchemey model to return a count and the data row per say for the model but I'm getting this `TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable`

My query is this

```
products = CollectionsModel.query(CollectionsModel.product_name, func.count(CollectionsModel.product_name)).filter_by(username=current_user.username).group_by(CollectionsModel.product_name, CollectionsModel.product_set_code).all()
```

And my Model is this

```
class CollectionsModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'collections'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    product_type = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    product_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    product_set_code = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    product_set_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    product_rarity = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    product_mana_cost = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    product_mana_cost_formatted = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    product_symbol_path = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    image_url = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    image_url_2 = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    foil = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    product_id = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    collection_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    tags = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    epoch_time = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    product_mana_symbols_svg = ''
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.